# Test app for iPad mini

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode8, ipad-mini

I am developing application for ipad. I have tested application for ipad 9.7 inch. I want to test app for ipad-mini which is a client requirement. How can i test my app for **iPad mini**. Although ipad-mini and ipad 9.7 inch have same pixel ratio but according to client there is still an issue on ipad-mini.
I am currently using xcode 8.3. 
There is no simulator device available for iPad mini.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to download simulators for iOS 9 from the XCode-Preferences-Components as shown in the below image because iPad mini is not updatable to iOS 10. Thats why it is not showing up in the simulator list. Once you will download the components for iOS 9 you will get it in your simulator list.
[image]

Comment: I have download iOS 8.1 and iOS 9.0 components. But still iPad-mini is not available in additional simulators. Only iPad-2 was added when i added iOS 9.0 components.

Answer (score 0):

There's no simulator for iPad mini. Either get one physical device or test on older version of ipad with similar resolution (or screen ratio)